# html spoiler and changing button

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

How can I change the src of an image input onclick and create a spoiler? I want this to happen:

(button that says: show) <- This button will have image 1

once clicked it will display a button with a different image

(button that says: hide) <- This button will have image 2

The only thing is, I want the src of the image of the button to change, but not the value of a button input, because I'm using an image input, not a button. Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showSpoiler(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>   
<div class="spoiler">
        <INPUT type="image" id="image" src="http://www.ogiatech.com/files/theme/icon_plus.png" value="" onclick="showSpoiler(this);" style="outline: none;" 
        onmouseover="this.src='http://www.ogiatech.com/files/theme/icon_plus_hover.png'" 
        onmouseout="this.src='http://www.ogiatech.com/files/theme/icon_plus.png'" />
        <div class="inner" style="display:none;">
        This is a spoiler!
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the the image src for the input with the id="image", AND the images for the rollover effect to change onclick. I know this may be confusing, but is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try another approach. Use a hidden input tag with src as you want. Later use a img to change the image as http://jsfiddle.net/G4Y5t/

```
 <div class="spoiler">
     <img id="image" 
          src="http://www.ogiatech.com/files/theme/icon_plus.png" 
          onclick="showSpoiler(this);" style="outline: none;"
          onmouseover="this.src='http://www.ogiatech.com/files/theme/icon_plus_hover.png'" 
          onmouseout="this.src='http://www.ogiatech.com/files/theme/icon_plus.png'" />
     <input type="hidden" value="your image src" />
     <div class="inner" style="display:none;">This is a spoiler!</div>
 </div>
```

You can change the `input` value attribute inside your function if you want.

Hope this help